# 404 Error on trying to download a zip file from REST service. JSON displayed on adding @ResponseBody

Tags: rest, zip, response

I am trying to download a zip file from the same folder as the REST controller. I keep getting a 404 not found error. On adding the `@ResponseBody` annotation, I am able to view the response as JSON. Where am I going wrong?

```php
@RequestMapping(value = "/GetFile", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces =MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)

public  Response getFile(){
    zipFilePath = "Test.zip"
    File file = new File(zipFilePath);

    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.zip");
    response.header("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));

    return response.build();
}
```